# How to Rotate 2D Sprite Towards Moving Direction?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, rotation, sprite

I have been searching all day and reading forums but I can't find a way that works. I'm making a top-down view horror game. When my player walks normally he can look around with the cursor in any direction, but when he wants to run he switches to "tank" controls and rotates toward the running direction. I need something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gs7y2b0xthU&t).
My player movement script so far:

```
public float walkSpeed;
public float runSpeed;
public float turnSpeed;
private Rigidbody2D rb;
public Camera cam;
private Vector2 moveDirection;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Update()
{
    ProcessInput();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    Move();
}

private void ProcessInput()
{
    float moveX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    float moveY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

    moveDirection = new Vector2(moveX, moveY).normalized;
}
void Move()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        //Looking toward movement direction should be applied here
    } else { 
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveDirection.x * walkSpeed, moveDirection.y * walkSpeed);

        Vector3 mousePosition = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        Vector2 direction = mousePosition - transform.position;
        float angle = Vector2.SignedAngle(Vector2.right, direction) - 90f;
        Vector3 targetRotation = new Vector3(0, 0, angle);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(targetRotation), turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: In Unity, you can modify the position of any object using it's transform component and it's position property. For example, if you have GameObject someSprite, you can assign a new value to someSprite.transform.position every frame. Usually it is done in your Update method, or, if you're working with physics, in the FixedUpdate method.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by substituting `moveDirection` instead of the mouse look direction, here it is enough to define a hypothetical variable called direction to detect the correct direction in each of these conditions.

```cs
var direction = new Vector2();
var currentSpeed = walkSpeed;

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
{
    direction = moveDirection;

    currentSpeed = runSpeed;

} else {
    direction = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
}

var angle = Vector2.SignedAngle(Vector2.right, direction) - 90f;
var targetRotation = new Vector3(0, 0, angle);
var lookTo = Quaternion.Euler(targetRotation);

rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveDirection.x, moveDirection.y) * runSpeed *Time.deltaTime;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, lookTo , turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: @Kinyl Thank you for your reply, but this isn't exactly what I'm looking for. Your solution makes the player look around even while running, so it's the same movement system as walking but faster :D My original plan was to use two different movement systems for walking and running, being able to look around with mouse while walking and only being able to look in the direction of running while well, running. Hope this clarifies some things

Comment: @Tony Unfortunately I understand your question now. In the upgraded answer, I solved the problem and tested it. :)